# How to unmarshal a SOAP Fault in a FaultMessageResolver?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, spring-ws

I'm new to Spring-WS, and slowly getting my head wrapped around it.  Right now, I'm writing a simple client to communicate with an existing WS.  I'm using the WebServiceTemplate and the marshalSendAndReceive method.  Everything works fine.

However, when a SOAP fault occurs, the WST throws a SoapFaultClientException.  I noticed that I can create my own FaultMessageResolver to check what is contained within the SOAP fault.  However, when I try to unmarshal the WebServiceMessage in my FaultMessageResolver, I get the following error message:

```
JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Fault"). Expected elements are ....
```

Obviously, my unmarshaller is not properly configured.  Do I have to generate the JAXB fault model myself using xjc to then be able to unmarshal the error?  I am somewhat amazed that this does not already exist.

Is there a better way to extra my custom error information from within my soap:fault response?  My error looks something like the following and I am trying to extract/access the serviceErrors item.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Blaze Data Error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns14:serviceErrors xmlns="http://www.nb.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateProfitabilityRequest" xmlns:ns13="http://www.nb.com/fw/errorMgmt" xmlns:ns14="http://www.nb.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/V1" >
               <ns13:faultstring>ServiceExecutionError</ns13:faultstring>
               <ns13:serviceError>
                  <ns13:errorCode>C10F1013</ns13:errorCode>
                  <ns13:errorType>B</ns13:errorType>
                  <ns13:errorMessage>Unable to retreive additional data</ns13:errorMessage>
                  <ns13:fieldName>Message error received from PHClient :  [An unexpected error code was received : system=PH context=[empty]]</ns13:fieldName>
                  <ns13:systemId>Calculator</ns13:systemId>
                  <ns13:time>2012-06-19 14:45:10.151-0400</ns13:time>
               </ns13:serviceError>
            </ns14:serviceErrors>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the error you're getting, it looks like you are trying to unmarshall XML source starting with the `<soap:Fault>` node. Without seeing your Java code, this means you are probably trying to unmarshall the source from `message.getSoapBody().getFault()`

You actually need to go deeper to get to the `<ns14:serviceErrors>` node.
You should be able to get to this by the following path... maybe not all at once :)

```
message.getSoapBody().getFault().getFaultDetail().getDetailEntries().next()
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's pretty much what I ended up doing.  But that only gets one fault info at a time, which I thought was pretty strange.  I would have expected some system to allow me to unmarhsal all faults into a list or array of faults.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate`. I run into the same issue with `Fault` unmarshalling. I resolved this problem by setting `WebServiceTemplate` property `checkConnectionForFault` to `false`. So in my case it was likely caused by the server not returning status 500 for the fault.

Then `spring-ws` parsed the fault and passed it to the default `FaultMessageResolver` and I got a regular `SoapFaultClientException` to catch.

But that got me only the message of the fault so I had to also add a custom `FaultMessageResolver` and extract the message along the same lines:

```
SoapFaultDetail faultDetail = ((SoapMessage) message).getSoapBody().getFault().getFaultDetail();
Iterator<SoapFaultDetailElement> detailEntries = faultDetail.getDetailEntries();
StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();

while (detailEntries.hasNext()) {
    SoapFaultDetailElement detailElement = detailEntries.next();
    Node node = ((DOMResult) detailElement.getResult()).getNode();
    CustomServiceFault serviceFault = (CustomServiceFault) marshaller.unmarshal(new DOMSource(node));
    errorMessage.append(serviceFault.getErrorCode() + ": " + serviceFault.getErrorMessage());
}
throw new CustomException(errorMessage.toString());
```

The marshaller is the same as the one used for the `WebserviceTemplate`.

Comment: Are you sure you using a marshaller? Should it be an unmarshaller instead?